# I need this printed like shown in my desired example

Tags: python, printing

This is the current code i have:

```
def render_histogram(values):

    rows = []

    for value in values:
        rows.append((" "'\n'*(max(values)-value))+("*"'\n'* value))

    return '\n'.join(rows)
print(render_histogram([4, 5, 3, 8, 1]))
```

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: what happened to 3?

Comment: Please don't attempt to delete a question once it has been answered. It defeats a purpose of this site; to help more people in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the built-in `zip()` method to transpose the `rows` list`:

```
def render_histogram(values):
    tallest = max(values)
    rows = [(value * '*').rjust(tallest) for value in values]
    return '\n'.join(''.join(s) for s in zip(*rows))

print(render_histogram([4, 5, 3, 8, 1]))
```

Output:

```
   * 
   * 
   * 
 * * 
** * 
**** 
**** 
*****
```